# Error retrieving jsonp from aurelia http client

Tags: javascript, jsonp, instagram-api, aurelia

I have an application I am creating using Aurelia.  I wish to retrieve the latest images from a user in instagram via ajax.  I tried using the [Aurelia http client](https://github.com/aurelia/http-client) because that's what the Flickr example on Aurelia's getting started page uses.

If I use `http.get`, then I get a CORS error from instagram.  Trying `http.jsonp`, the inspected response shows the [correct format](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/), but I get what looks like a parsing error (Unexpected token ":") before the callback that handles the response is being executed.

I *am* able to successfully retrieve the images via AJAX using jQuery, but I am curious to know what I am doing wrong with the Aurelia http client.

Here are the relevant bits of the view model:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Welcome {
  images = [];
  url = '[INSTAGRAM_URL]';

  constructor(http){
    this.http = http;
  }

  activate(){
    return this.http.jsonp(this.url).then(response => {
      this.images = response.data.map(function (d) {
            return {
                src: d.images.standard_resolution.url,
                caption: d.caption.text,
                when: d.created_time
            };
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instagram API expects `callback` GET parameter to be present in request URL. This parameter should be a function name to wrap response object into (Aurelia will add something like `&callback=jsonp_callback_59563`). The reason why it works with jQuery.jsonp is that it adds `callback` parameter automatically behind the scene.

Correct code then should be:

```
return this.http.jsonp(this.url, 'callback').then(response => {
  this.images = response.content.data.map(function (d) {
        return {
            src: d.images.standard_resolution.url,
            caption: d.caption.text,
            when: d.created_time
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah!  When I read the documentation, I read "callback" as simply "a callback" (in an arbitrary sort of way) - not that the parameter name actually needs to be named "callback"....  I should read more closely.  Thanks!