# aurelia aurelia-http-client jsonp

Tags: javascript, api, jsonp, aurelia

I try to query an api which is not the same origin with the aurelia-http-client.

My code pretty simple :

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';

export class App {

    constructor(){

    console.log("constructor called");

        let url = 'http://localhost:8081/all';

        let client = new HttpClient();

        client
            .jsonp(url)
            .then(data => {
                console.log("datas");
                console.log(data);
            });

    }

}
```

Nothing happens, I can see in network that the url is called, my api engine logs an entry but I never enter in the "then" of the "promise"...

What's wrong ?

Update :

I give you some screenshots with catch

[code source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkqCo.png)
[browser result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PW7W.png)

With JQuery on the same machine no problems.

Comment: you code seems fine... any specific reason for `jsonp`? does it work with `get`?

Comment: Hi fabio, yes I because the page is deserve by :9000 and my api are in :8081. In production, it's 2 different machines. I tried with JQuery and no problems to get jsonp datas. I waste maybe 2 hours to try with different libraries but its a bit complicated to work with typescript... First try with aurelia and I think last try because in 2 hours I would have finished my page...

Comment: You might add a .catch(()=>) to the end of that statement to see if there are any errors being generated by the promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading this post [other jsonp case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793604/error-retrieving-jsonp-from-aurelia-http-client?rq=1) I try to add the work "callback" and now it works !!!

so call jsonp(url, 'callback')

```
client.jsonp(url, 'callback')
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a direct answer but just a suggestion, I would rather use the aurelia API as I found it more consistent and stable.

just add it as plugin in you main :

```
.plugin('aurelia-api', config => {
      config.registerEndpoint('github', 'https://api.github.com/');
    });
```

and use it as:
    import {Endpoint} from 'aurelia-api':

```
@autoinject
export class Users{
  constructor(private githubEndpoint){
  }

  activate() {
    return this.githubEndpoint.find('users')
      .then(users => this.users = users);
  }
}
```

Source: https://aurelia-api.spoonx.org/Quick%20start.html